Получение вложенного массива из файла json с помощью Retofit Kotlin
получил данные с сайта в формате json  используя retrofit на Kotlin.все вроде бы нормально , но есть затруднение со вложенными массивами, прошу помочь.
Файл:
 {
    "location":
    {},
    "current":
    {},
    "forecast":
    {
        "forecastday": [
        {
            "hour": [
            {
                "time_epoch": 1719010800,
                "time": "2024-06-22 00:00"
               
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
}

под него сделал Data класс:
data class Weatherapi(
val forecast: Forecast
)

data class Forecast(
    val forecastday:List<ForecastDay>
)

data class ForecastDay(
       val hour:  List<HourW>? = null
)

data class HourW(
    val time_epoch: String?=null,
    val time: String?=null,
) 

Проблема -получение списка в виде LazyRow из data class HourW
Код:

 val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
            var forecast by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<ForecastDay>()) }
            var hourW by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<HourW>()) }
            val interseptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interseptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interseptor).build()
            val retofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseurl).client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
            val retofitApi = retofit.create(Api_Weaterapi::class.java)
            scope.launch {
                val result = retofitApi.Get3day(M_Api, city, lang, dayW = dayW)

                forecast = result.forecast.forecastday

            }

            Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {

                for (i in 0 until forecast.size) {
                    val dd = forecast[i].hour.toString()
                    LazyRow {
                        itemsIndexed(forecast[i].hour) { j, item ->
                         W_hourCard(hourW = item)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


вызываемая ф-я (Карточка) :
@Composable
fun W_hourCard(hourW: HourW?) {

    val timeW = hourW?.time

    Card(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(2.dp)
    ) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
               
            Text(text = timeW.toString())//Time

        }
    }

}

В

LazyRow
ругается на несоответствие типов



Может ему просто nullable не нравится?

Да, Вы правы. убрал null  и пошло. Спасибо!
